# Increase app performances with ElasticSearch on NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, elasticsearch, sequelize.js

I didn't find exactly what I'm looking for and no one to explain me, so I ask here. Hope this is not a duplicate…

I have an application that run on NodeJS with the ORM sequelize and a MySQL database. The project start one year ago.

I would like, now, to increase performances etc, install ElasticSearch. But I'm not sure if I can.

Can I just tell my elasticserver, where my database is, and magically, it does the mapping alone ? 
Or Have I to insert my data on elasticSearch ?

All my infrastructure is hosted on AWS, I'm using RDS. May be it will help ? 
In fact I don't know where to put the elasticSearch layer ? Do you have any ideas to help me.

Because, I already worked with Symfony and the FosElasticaBundle, but it works pretty well that I don't know how.

Comment: You might want to try over at http://discuss.elastic.co I suspect your question is too broad for Stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks @DougT., I'm going to post this question over there, and come back to post the answer here, if I have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDPATE:

- you can use the ES http api
- your existing data in your database can you bulk index
- You have to handle changes in your database, so you can use the observe pattern, such as created(), saved(), deleted(), so you can in these methods handle the ES actions to created, update or delete a document

Elasticsearch (ES) is a speed machine with a lot of possibilities (advanced queries, stats, etc.), not a database (read why here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql).

- It's distributed (can work/share work via multiple servers)
- It's document based (json documents, for example with nested, parent/child relationships)
- It's mapping based
- It's indexing based

More here: https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

You can use types in ES (like tables in your database).

ES uses indexed data, based on the mapping. Therefore, you still need a database and index the data (denormalized) to ES. You can query, filter, aggregate, analyze the data in your index.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I'have already a database ? With My ORM ? How can I notify elastic search, there is new entries ? Have I to select from elasticsearch and insert / update to mysql database manually ? I'm a little confused

Comment: What i'm doing is, in a first place, optimizing my existing app, before trying to add more layers (for now). But I'll keep in my mind your advices. 
Thanks for your answer , really appreciated. @Schellingerht